# Postgress creating a partition without lock

Tags: postgresql, locking

I want to create a partition on a table that has data. With the current architecture creating a  partition is creating a lock on the database. How to create a partition without locking?

Creating the partition results in deadlock now

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the SQL commands you are running as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. ([edit] your question, please to not put code in comments)

Comment: From the manual: Attaching a partition acquires a SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock on the parent table. There is always some type of lock, you can't do anything in your database without locks. But a deadlock sounds like an application error on your side.